# Unable to Play mp4 with video.js or html5

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

I am able to play the video file if it is enclosed with the EMBED tag.  However, since that is a dying tag, I'd like to use html5.  So far I've had no luck.  I've also attempted using video.js.  Chrome doesn't give me a clear error, however firefox says it was unable to decode the video when using the video.js.  It's not clear to me why.  The file is one that is automatically generated every ten minutes (it's for a weather webcam). I've attached info about the file below.  The info was extracted using MediaInfo:

```
General
Count                                    : 284
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Inform                                   : MPEG-4 (Base Media): 428 KiB, 6s 334ms
Count of video streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : MPEG-4 Visual
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : MPEG-4 Visual
Codecs Video                             : MPEG-4 Visual
File name                                : tensecondvideo
File extension                           : mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec/Extensions usually used            : mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma f4v
File size                                : 438299
File size                                : 428 KiB
File size                                : 428 KiB
File size                                : 428 KiB
File size                                : 428 KiB
File size                                : 428.0 KiB
Duration                                 : 6334
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:06.334
Overall bit rate                         : 553583
Overall bit rate                         : 554 Kbps
Stream size                              : 941
Stream size                              : 941 Bytes (0%)
Stream size                              : 941 Bytes
Stream size                              : 941 Bytes
Stream size                              : 941 Bytes
Stream size                              : 941.0 Bytes
Stream size                              : 941 Bytes (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00215
HeaderSize                               : 36
DataSize                                 : 437366
FooterSize                               : 897
IsStreamable                             : No
File creation date                       : UTC 2013-05-16 13:17:34.737
File creation date (local)               : 2013-05-16 09:17:34.737
File last modification date              : UTC 2013-05-16 13:12:12.000
File last modification date (local)      : 2013-05-16 09:12:12.000
Writing application                      : Lavf54.59.106

Video
Count                                    : 263
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
Inform                                   : 552 Kbps, 1280*720 (16:9), at 3.000 fps, MPEG-4 Visual (Simple@L1)
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L1
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : 0
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Internet media type                      : video/MP4V-ES
Codec ID                                 : 20
Codec                                    : MPEG-4V
Codec                                    : MPEG-4 Visual
Codec/Family                             : MPEG-4V
Codec/CC                                 : 20
Codec profile                            : Simple@L1
Codec settings, Packet bitstream         : No
Codec settings, BVOP                     : No
Codec settings, QPel                     : No
Codec settings, GMC                      : 0
Codec settings, GMC                      : No warppoints
Codec settings, Matrix                   : Default (H.263)
Duration                                 : 6334
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 6s 334ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:06.334
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 552452
Bit rate                                 : 552 Kbps
Width                                    : 1280
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.778
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : CFR
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 3.000
Frame rate                               : 3.000 fps
Frame count                              : 19
Resolution                               : 8
Resolution                               : 8 bits
Colorimetry                              : 4:2:0
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Interlacement                            : PPF
Interlacement                            : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.200
Delay                                    : 0
Delay                                    : 00:00:00.000
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Stream size                              : 437358
Stream size                              : 427 KiB (100%)
Stream size                              : 427 KiB
Stream size                              : 427 KiB
Stream size                              : 427 KiB
Stream size                              : 427.1 KiB
Stream size                              : 427 KiB (100%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.99785
Writing library                          : Lavc54.86.100
Writing library                          : Lavc54.86.100
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an MP4, but using the [MPEG-4 Visual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2) video codec which the browsers' video element (or Flash fallback) cannot play. When using an embed element Quicktime or some other plugin will be playing them.

You should convert these to h.264 (and webm if you don't want to use Flash fallback on Firefox) for HTML5 video.

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about MP4 for streaming using [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) you need to supply a good fragmented mp4 file to MSE SourceBuffer. Obtaining a Fragmented mp4 data chunk (or file) can be achieved by any one method of these two:-

- use ffmpeg to create the fragmented mp4 file:  Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE

  - `ffmpeg -i non_fragmented.mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof fragmented.mp4`
  - OR `ffmpeg -i trailer_1080p.mov -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof bunny_fragmented.mp4`
- You may use [mp4box.js](https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/) for streaming normal mp4 segments (non-fragmented mp4 streaming)

  - mp4box.js is capable to do fragmentation on-the-fly according to its README.

So, Either way we are using fragmented MP4 for streaming using MSE

IMO, that mp4box alternative looks much better to me. I have not yet tried it though. I made the suggestion based on the Readme

- NB: mp4box.js uses Bento4 which is recommended in the MDN link that I mentioned in the first point regarding ffmpeg